# Python callback fails with access violation

Tags: python, callback, ctypes

I can call functions in my dll from python.
When I call a dll function that does a callback to my python code it fails.
It there some sort of mutex blocking my callback?

```
from ctypes import *
import _ctypes

@CFUNCTYPE(None)
def Test():
    print ("Test here")
    return

def SetUpDll():
    print ("Setting read / write callback functions...")
    windll.ClaRUN.AttachThreadToClarion(1)
    MyDll = CDLL('IC2_CommsServer.dll')

    SetTestFunc = getattr(MyDll, "SETTESTFUNC@Fl")
    SetTestFunc (Test)

    CallTestFunc = getattr(MyDll, "CALLTESTFUNC@F")
    CallTestFunc()

    _ctypes.FreeLibrary(MyDll._handle)
    _ctypes.FreeLibrary(windll.ClaRUN._handle)

    print ("Done.")


SetUpDll()

C:\Users\Derek\anaconda3_32\python.exe Z:/ps_IC2_dll/ps_IC2_dll.py
Setting read / write callback functions...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/ps_IC2_dll/ps_IC2_dll.py", line 48, in <module>
    SetUpDll()
  File "Z:/ps_IC2_dll/ps_IC2_dll.py", line 40, in SetUpDll
    CallTestFunc()
OSError: exception: access violation writing 0x009EF77C

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: I think I have located the problem.
SetTestFunc (Test)  <<<  this does not pass the callback address.
This passes a handle to the Test object.

How do I get the actual funtion address?

Comment: It's *Undefined Behavior*. Most likely, it's a dupe of [\[SO\]: C function called from Python via ctypes returns incorrect value (@CristiFati's answer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58610333/c-function-called-from-python-via-ctypes-returns-incorrect-value/58611011#58611011), but there might be other issues as well.

Comment: Yes!   :-)

added from your other answer:

SetTestFunc.restype = None
SetTestFunc.argtypes = [CFUNCTYPE(None)]

Now it works

Comment: Then please mark the question as a duplicate of the other one (by pressing the *close* button, and pasting the other question *URL*).

Comment: There is another issue.  :-(
Native clarion functions use a C calling convention but...  parameters are not compatible.

I have changed all my DLL functions to be C functions and now the code works correctly.

Comment: What do you mean by "*C calling convention*". If it's *cdecl*, then all you have to change is `cdll.ClaRUN.AttachThreadToClarion(1)`.

Comment: Clarion uses its own proprietary Topspeed C register passing format.   So it is C but 100% NOT cdecl compatible.

Answer (score 0):

First, on Windows, the *ctypes* uses win32 structured exception handling to prevent crashes from general protection faults when functions are called with invalid argument values.

You have a bad call for this line of code:

```
CallTestFunc = getattr(MyDll, "CALLTESTFUNC@F")
```

Try to review your code, then see if the problem is from *ps_IC2_dll.py* build area.

Comment: Thanks Catalin,

The failure is actually after the next line.   CallTestFunc().

It calls a simple test function in my dll which outputs a debug message and then executes the callback to python.

I see the debug message so the CallTestFunc() works.
It is the callback to the python Test() that fails.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to CristiFati who provided half of the answer.

This code now works,  note that the clarion dll functions are now prototyped as ,C
A nice side effect is that the function names loose the "@F" suffix and so the code is simpler.

```
from ctypes import *
import _ctypes

@CFUNCTYPE(None)
def Test():
    print ("Test here")
    return

def SetUpDll():
    print ("Setting read / write callback functions...  Ptr=", sizeof(c_void_p), "bytes")
    assert sizeof(c_void_p) == 4

    ClaRTL = CDLL('./ClaRUN.dll')
    MyDll = CDLL('./IC2_CommsServer.dll')

    ClaRTL.AttachThreadToClarion.restype = None
    ClaRTL.AttachThreadToClarion.argtypes = [c_int32]
    ClaRTL.AttachThreadToClarion(1)

    MyDll.SETTESTFUNC.restype = None
    MyDll.SETTESTFUNC.argtypes = [CFUNCTYPE(None)]
    MyDll.SETTESTFUNC (Test)

    MyDll.CALLTESTFUNC.restype = None
    MyDll.CALLTESTFUNC ()

    _ctypes.FreeLibrary(MyDll._handle)
    _ctypes.FreeLibrary(ClaRTL._handle)

    print ("Done.")


SetUpDll()
```

Output is now:

```
C:\Users\Derek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38-32\python.exe Z:/ps_IC2_dll/ps_IC2_dll.py
Setting read / write callback functions...  Ptr= 4 bytes
Test here
Done.

Process finished with exit code 0
```